# flex: how to decrease gap between each text element?

Tags: apache-flex, layout

I have an mx:vbox and inside i have several mx:text elements.
how do i decrease the gap between each line of text that is shown ?
i tried doing the following:

```
  <mx:VBox borderColor="black" borderStyle="inset" width="80%" verticalGap="0" paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0">
             <mx:Text text="a" width="80%" paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0"/>
             <mx:Text text="b" width="80%" paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0"/> 
             <mx:Text text="c"  width="80%" paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0"/>
             <mx:Text text="d" width="80%"   paddingBottom="0" paddingTop="0"/>
            </mx:VBox>
```

and still there is a big gap between each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting verticalGap to a negative amount, eg.  verticalGap="-10"

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use the Label component instead (if you don't need multi-line text).  Or set a specific height value on the Text components.